# SQL select rows containing empty field using GROUP BY, HAVING COUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, having

What I'm trying to do is very similar to [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3800551/4613360)

but other than select first row after `ORDER BY number DESC`, I want to select a row shows up multiple times in database (has changed name in past) AND empty field under Change_Name_to.

For example, I have a table that shows person's name change history and current name.

```
+--------+--------------+----------------+
| UserID | Current_Name | Change_Name_to |
+--------+--------------+----------------+
|     30 | Name3        |                |
|     30 | Name2        | Name3          |
|     30 | Name1        | Name2          |
|     10 | Name5        |                |
|     20 | Name7        |                |
|     20 | Name6        | Name7          |
+--------+--------------+----------------+
```

what I want to do here is

```
+--------+--------------+----------------+
| UserID | Current_Name | Change_Name_to |
+--------+--------------+----------------+
|     30 | Name3        |                |
|     20 | Name7        |                |
+--------+--------------+----------------+
```

How should I do this?

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) FROM `docs` GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(UserID) > 1
```

I understand this doesn't work, but something like this is something I wanted to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do what you want using:

```
select d.*
from docs d
where d.change_name_to is null and
      exists (select 1
              from docs d2
              where d2.userid = d.userid and d2.change_name_to is not null
             );
```

Comment: this was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot, it was very clear and easy to understand as soon as I saw your query.

Answer (score 2):

Based on that sample data, all you need is

```
select * 
from docs d
where d.change_name_to is null
and UserID in (select UserID from docs group by UserID having count(UserID) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check on the next:

```
SELECT
  l.UserID, l.Current_Name, l.Change_Name_to
FROM @docs l JOIN @docs r
  ON l.UserID = r.UserID AND
     l.Current_Name = r.Change_Name_to
WHERE l.Change_Name_to IS NULL AND
      r.Change_Name_to IS NOT NULL;
```